# Change file extension while generating output file using uglifycss

Tags: shell, find, uglifycss

I am using the uglifycss npm package to minify all the CSS files from the project output directory. I am executing the following post-build script to minify the CSS files content and rename the files by appending `*.min.css`

```
find dist/assets/css/ -type f -name "*.css" -exec uglifycss --output {}.min.css {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Files before executing the script:

[image]

Files after executing the script:

[image]

I want to remove existing `.css` from full filename path and append `.min.css` to it. I have tried several solutions but couldn't achieve the expected outcome. I have gone through the [uglifycss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifycss) docs but couldn't find anything. Is there a way I can trim the extension from {} file path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `-exec`, the `{}` is substituted with the complete filename and there is no direct way to remove the extension from `{}`. One way would be to use shell manipulation

```
find dist/assets/css/ -type f -name "*.css" -exec sh -c '
    for file ; do
        uglifycss --output "${file%.css}.min.css" "$file"
        rm -- "$file"
    done
' _ {} +
```

The trick is with parameter expansion `${file%.css}.min.css`, the extension `.css` is removed and the part `.min.css` is added back.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227662/how-to-rename-multiple-files-using-find) and transform it to your needs like this

```
find dist/assets/css/ -type f -name "*.css" -exec bash -c 'name="{}"; uglifycss --output "${name//css/min.css}" "$name"' \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: This spawns a bash shell for each occurrence of the .css file found and might do the substitution incorrectly if the filename is for e.g. `cssmain.css`